# MVC2 nested master could not load type?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, master-pages

I've just begun experimenting with nested masters in MVC2. I'm not quite sure why I am getting this error.

`Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'MySite.Views.Shared.Master'.`

I used the add item wizard, created `Master.master`, and selected it's master to be `Site.Master`. In one of my views I changed the `MasterPageFile` from `Site.Master` to `Master.master`.  I haven't changed any contents. What have I gotten wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you've added a Master Page and not a MVC Master Page. You need to make sure that both of your master pages inherit from `System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage`.

So your master page directives should look like this:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage" %>
```

AND

```
<%@ Master MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage" %>
```

HTHs,
Charles